# Download a copy of Adobe CQ5

Tags: aem

I would like to take a look at Adobe CQ5 CMS system. Does anybody know if I can download it to my developer computer? I can not find link on web site.

I know Adobe offers CRX as opensource - but my interest is in CQ5 cms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to my rep you need to engage with Adobe to get a copy. We don't have it in house yet as the do want a training session so that users aren't frustrated with the complexity.  I've played around on a test site and also played with it at conventions and it seems like one of the better designed CMS options at the moment.

Answer (score 11):

You can download it. Adobe has re-branded and re-released Communique since acquiring Day Software. CQ5 is now known as ADEP. Read about it in Adobe's ADEP Architecture Guide: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/solutions/customer-experience-solutions/enterprise-platform/pdfs/adep-2011-architecture-considerations-for-new-and-existing-customers-ue.pdf. Here is an excerpt:

> The Day CQ and CRX product lines have been incorporated into ADEP. CRX forms the foundation of the Experience Services stack, and CQ has been branded as the new Web Experience Management solution.
> Architecturally, these products are unchanged, enabling a smooth upgrade experience in the future.
>
> New customers requiring the web content management capabilities of CQ should purchase and develop
> their applications on one of the Web Experience Management solution editions (Basic, Standard, Premium).
> The Web Experience Management solution incorporates all the capabilities of CQ 5.4.

Download a trial version of ADEP here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/enterprise-platform/trial-downloads.html

Comment: Note that, since the above comment was written, the CQ product is back at http://www.adobe.com/products/cq.html

Comment: Now (July 2013) called Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) - see http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current.html

Comment: @Yetimoner: Trial download link you posted not working anymore :(

Comment: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html now says (July 2013) `Business partners can request download access via spphelp@adobe.com`

Answer (score 5):

I am working on CQ5, its a very advanced CMS tool as compared to the others. But its not a open source like other Drupal, Joomla, etc. You have to purchase the developer suite.

Refer to the links for [online document support](http://dev.day.com/docs/en.html).

Comment: i am new to adobe CQ5. I have only Adobe Flex work experience. I want to learn CQ5, is it typical? and please share the tutorial links.

Comment: Ravi, some basic language foundations will carry over, but it's a completely different stack than Flex. Pretty much you are looking at CRX (JCR) + Sling + OSGI (I believe running on Felix) + J2EE + ExtJS (for a lot of the dialog systems etc)

Answer (score 3):

CQ5 generally requires a license.  However, you CAN get started with the various components.  CQ5 is a system built on top of Felix (OSGi console), Jackrabbit(JCR), and a few other pieces, e.g. ExtJS for a lot of front end stuff.  If you learn these technologies you won't 'know' CQ5 but you will have a big step up in terms of learning it.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is learn SLING.

http://sling.apache.org/documentation/getting-started/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html

If you really understand Sling and OSGI, the JCR stuff is pretty trivial.  Mastery of these core technologies makes CQ/AEM pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe CQ5 is a tool being used for creating websites having content-oriented pages. This is a product of  Adobe, so you cannot get it free. 
Instead, to get a glimpse of it, please refer developer website of Day OR adobe CQ. Also, we have some useful URLs, which can be referred: http://vimeo.com/39504016 (an introduction video) ; http://docs.adobe.com/  ; http://adobecq5interviewquestions.wordpress.com/introduction-to-cq/