# How to download AEM 5.6 package from Adobe

Tags: adobe, aem

I could not able to download AEM 5.6 package in any of the websites. Is there any link available to download

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a copy of Adobe CQ5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584447/download-a-copy-of-adobe-cq5)

Answer (score 0):

Download a trial version of ADEP [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/enterprise-platform/trial-downloads.html).